# Change folder name

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm try to change folder name, but I get the next error:

```
{ [Error: EPERM, rename 'c:\nodejs\files\fm\File Manager\files\temp']
   errno: -4048,
   code: 'EPERM',
   path: 'c:\\nodejs\\files\\fm\\File Manager\\files\\temp' }
```

My code is:

```
fs.rename(path + GET["fname"], path + GET['newname'], function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
```

Its works great with files, but with folders its throw an error

I think that this function (`rename`) dosent work on foldes, any ideas?

Comment: Permission problem on folder, check them

Comment: @Michelem , You right, it was `Read Only`, tell me something, if there is no special function to change folders names, how the `rename` function knows if the path that I give her its Folder or File?

Comment: Why should it know it? It's working the same way when you rename a file or a folder.

Comment: @Michelem , But how the function knows if the Oldpath (name) that I give her its a folder or file? assume that I have file and folder with the same name, how the function will know what to rename?

Comment: You can't have a file and a folder with the same name in the same place. Your files probably have an extension you don't see (I recommend to enable it).